# django Page not found (404), map cannot be found

Tags: python, django

I was working on this django project where I keep getting this error when I am trying to access sightings/map

Error Message:

Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://35.188.51.159/sightings/map/

Raised by:  sightings.views.detail"

And the terminal is prompting:

```
Not Found: /sightings/map/
[20/Oct/2020 15:43:07] "GET /sightings/map/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1742
```

Here is my sightings/views.py file which gives the map:

```
def show_map(request):
    sightings = Squirrel.objects.all()[:100]
    context = {
        'sightings': sightings
    }
    return render(request, 'sightings/map.html', context)
```

And the sightings/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
  
from . import views
app_name = 'sightings'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
    path('stats/', views.stats, name='stats'),
    path('<squirrel_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('map/', views.show_map, name='show_map'),
]
```

Here's the main url file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
import sightings.views as views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sightings/', include('sightings.urls'))
```

All my other functions work just fine, the only issue is map.

Comment: Can you show your main `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look which view raises the 404 you will notice it's `sightings.views.detail`.
That view is mapped to `path('<squirrel_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),`.

What this means is anything that is found under `sightings/` will be treated as an url parameter, for example if you call `sightings/map` it will treat `map` as an `squirrel_id` and will call `views.detail`.

Perhaps you have some `get_object_or_404` logic in `views.detail` which returns 404 if you don't match any squirrel(?) with the given `<squirrel_id>`.

If you want to call `show_map` view, then:

1. Change your pattern that has urlparameter to something unique, maybe `'detail/<squirrel_id>/'`.
2. Move `'map/'` above `'<squirrel_id>/'`, because url matching follows positional order.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently, the order does matter. I've struggled with this for a while, Thanks again